# cannot use &cfg (value of type *aws.Config) as *aws.Config value in argument to session.NewSession

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to get a new AWS Session like this:

```
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

awsSession, err := session.NewSession(&cfg)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But I get a confusing (at least to me) error:

> cannot use &cfg (value of type *aws.Config) as *aws.Config value in argument to session.NewSession

The signature of `NewSession()` looks like this:

```
func NewSession(cfgs ...*aws.Config) (*Session, error)
```

Does the fact that `NewSession()` is a variadic function play any role in producing this error?

Why does the error go away if I pass a literal `aws.Config{}` like this?

```
awsSession, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up AWS SDK versions.

The package `session` exists in AWS SDK v1 with import path [`github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session) and expects arguments of type `"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws".Config`. It does not exist in AWS SDK v2.

The `config` package you were loading your configs from instead is from AWS SDK v2 with import path [`github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config) therefore `LoadDefaultConfigs` returns `"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config".Config`.

These are not the same type and the compiler is telling you that (albeit with a partially useful error message).

You have to keep your AWS SDK versions consistent. With v2, you are supposed to instantiate the specific AWS services with the config, instead of a session. For example `s3.New(&cfg)`.

Comment: You're right! Versions were mixed up. Also there's no reason for me to be using v1 at all, since v2 is GA. Thanks!

Comment: @ViníciusFerraz yeah unless you have to maintain legacy code, definitely use v2